# SerialPort (.Net 4.0) ReadTo method lead to sistematic timeout

Tags: c#, serial-port

In  my scenario there are one or two serial port. If only one port is configured, that port can be dedicated to a PLC or to a Scale.

The PLC communicate only when user push some button on the machine, the Scale instead constantly poll the measured that has weighted. If only one port is configured there are no issue.

When two port are configured the communication protocol change a bit, if user push the PLC's weight button PLC send a weight request. If that request is listened on DataReceived event the Scale port is opened and the polled value is readen.

Now i have to admit that the legacy code that i will paste here is not the best code possible, and that is bad that it use the same DataReceived event for both the ports; but that code had work for quite a lot (about six years). Recently the Scale has been changed and the program had stoped working properly (only in the two port configuration) raising a sistematic timeout exception. I have sniffed the traffic and nothing change with protocol or data format.

Here the problematic piece of code :

```
private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_myLockSerialPort)
    {
        string source = "No Data" ;

        try
        {
            if (sender == null)
                return;

            SerialPort genericPort = (SerialPort)sender;

            if (genericPort.Equals(ScalePort))
            {
                if (genericPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    source = "Scale" ;
                    string datas = string.Empty;
                    datas = genericPort.ReadTo(_currentConfiguration.ReadToForPese);
                    ReadDataFromScale(genericPort, datas);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (genericPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    source = "PLC" ;
                    string datas = string.Empty;
                    datas = genericPort.ReadTo(_currentConfiguration.ReadToForPlc);
                    ReadDataFromPlc(genericPort, datas);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeoutException)
        {
            //Handle Timeout
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //Handle Other Errors
        }
    }
}
```

The question is if there is something in the ReadTo method or in the polling interval that can explain that behaviour.
I would underline that nothing in the data exchange format has changed, so the character used to terminate the communication are still in place (and present in  the sniffed traffic).

Comment: It is not the code.  Probably a setting on the Scale that changed where the 2nd port is not configured at the correct rate or an option on scale changed.  You are timing out because send a command to get one value from the scale and the scale isn't recognizing the command.  Did any thing on the PC change that would of affect the com port number for second port?  Did you swap port 1 and port 2?

Comment: @jdweng it was my firs thought. But i was able to sniff traffic as usual (listening the same ports, with usual baudrate, pariry etc).
The only thing that seems to be changed is the polling period (the scale push messages with the weight value pc listen using events), it was about half a seconds before the update and few milliseconds now.

Comment: You may not being getting all the bytes from the scale at the same time.  You  You are uing ReadTo() and ReadDataFromScale() may work different with a different scale.  Also check that you do not have handshaking turned on (hardware or software).

Comment: mmm ReadTo should be a blocking call and wait until all the bytes (included the terminator) are received. The polling period (frequency at which scale push values) used by the scale is pretty fast so i find strange this is the casue of the problem (i have incresed the timeout up to 10s during the investigation).

The method ReadDataFromScale is never reached because the ReadTo lead to a timeout.
I will investigate better the handshaking parameter you pointed out. 
Thanks.

Comment: Ps :
changing the method and using ReadByte() for every bytes in the BytesToRead (until the terminator is found) seems solve the problem.
But this seems to higlight the fact that this issue is due port configuration or polling frequency not code. And if possibile i would solve the issue without update this legacy program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, NO, NO!!! If you had a text file normally you would use ReadLine() method to read one line at a time.  With ports or sockets data is coming at you at real time and the program is probably running faster than the data so you will not get a full line at one time.  The serial uart in the PC has only a small read buffer (could be as small as 8 bytes).  Windows is using timers to move the serial port data into a stream.  Your program is reading the windows stream.  So the actual data received is a combination of how fast the sender is sending data, the latency of the UART, the latency of Windows, and the latency of the Net Library.  It is not a configuration issue.  It is a real time issue.

Comment: Sorry i miss the point.
AFAIK ReadTo method wait until the buffer contain all the characters, terminator included.
In my case scale push data every ~10ms and i need two data push to have the complete message, so it will take about ~20ms to have the entire message.
I have configured the port timeout up to 10s during my investigation, so i expect that at least one complete message is received.
What have i misunderstood?

Comment: Adding timers is a kludge.  I usually just recommend using the DataReceive event and appending the receive data into a buffer.  Then search buffer for end character and when found remove the entire scale reading and process.  I don't like looping until end character is found which can hangup a form.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using two `SerialPort` classes, one for your scale and one for the PLC in which they would have their own `DataReceived` events. As others have suggested, you should append characters until you see your end character, then parse the string with your methods you wrote.  Below is an example where Line Feed (LF) is my end character I'm looking for.

```
StringBuilder sbScale = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbPLC = new StringBuilder();
char LF = (char)10;

private void serialPortScale_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPortScale.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sbScale.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sbScale.ToString();
            sbScale.Clear();

            ReadDataFromScale(CurrentLine);
        }
        else
        {
            sbScale.Append(c);
        }
    }
}

private void serialPortPLC_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPortPLC.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sbPLC.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sbPLC.ToString();
            sbPLC.Clear();

            ReadDataFromPlc(CurrentLine);
        }
        else
        {
            sbPLC.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

You could try to implement that into one `DataReceived` event, but it can be messy.  I think have dedicated classes to each device is much cleaner and easier to read, especially if someone has to take over the code some day after you.  Also I clear the string builder immediately, because the `DataReceived` event is threaded, so it can fire while you're already in there.